# how i can fix error about chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have written a simple extension just to learn how it works.

Manifest V3:

```
{  "name": "Sample",
   "version": "1.0",
   "manifest_version": 3,
   "action": {
      "default_name": "Sample",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
 },
"permissions": ["tabs", "storage", "activeTab", "clipboardRead", "scripting"],
"host_permissions": ["http://*/", "file://*/*", "https://*/", "*://*/*"]
}
```

popup.html:

```
.....
.....
<button id='getInfo' >GET</button>
.....
.....
```

popup.js:

```
....
document.getElementById("getInfo").addEventListener("click", function() {

chrome.tabs.query(
        {active: true, currentWindow: true},
        (tabs) => {
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: {tabId: tabs[0].id},
                file: ['func.js'],
            });
        });
 }
```

func.js:

```
alert("extension sample")
```

When i press the button 'GET' i receive an error in extension manager page.
The error says: "Error handling response: TypeError: Error in invocation of scripting.executeScript(scripting.ScriptInjection injection, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'injection': Unexpected property: 'file'."

I have tried with function instead of the file and it works.

How i can fix this error? Thank you.

Comment: It's `files` not `file`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chrome.scripting.executeScript` does not have `file` property.
You should use `files` property.

Search for "`executeScript`" in the official Google documentation below to see the sample.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/